# How to efficiently repair data in large kafka / kafka streams applications

Tags: apache-kafka, scalability, apache-kafka-streams

**Project**:

the application i am working on processes financial transaction (orders and trade) data, several millions per day.

the data is fed into a kafka topic.

kafka streams microservices aggregate the information (e.g. nr of trades per stock), and this data is consumed by other software. In addition, the data is persisted in mongodb.

**Problem:**

the data sent to the topic needs to be sometimes modified, e.g. changes of prices due to bug or misconfiguration.

Since kafka is append-only, i do the correction in mongodb, and after that, the corrected data is piped into a new kafka topic, leading to a complete re-calculations of the downstream aggregations.

However, this process causes scalability concerns, as more and more data needs to be replayed over time.

**Question**

I am considering splitting the large kafka topic into daily topics, so that only a single day's topics needs to be replayed in most cases of data repair.

My question is if this is a plausible way to address this problem or if there are better solutions to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data repairing or in general error handling and Kafka heavily depends on the use case. In our case we build our system based on the CQRS + event sourcing principles (generic description [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/event-sourcing-cqrs-stream-processing-apache-kafka-whats-connection/)) and as a result for data repairing we are using "compensating events" (i.e. an event that amends the effects of another event) and eventually the system will be consistent.

Comment: thanks for the response. It does not fully solve my particular problem, but i acknowledge that it is a perfectly valid answer.